# Как определить вид придаточного предложения и значение союза ЧТОБЫ?

Tags: грамматика, союзы, сложное-предложение

***У меня нет времени, чтобы играть.***

Предложение рассматривалось на форуме [https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/18369/should-the-verb-after-Чтобы-be-infinitive-or-in-the-past-tense](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/18369/should-the-verb-after-%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-be-infinitive-or-in-the-past-tense)

Изучающим русский язык сложно различать изъяснительный и целевой союзы ЧТОБЫ (возможно, они знают только о союзе со значением цели).

Изъяснительный союз ЧТОБЫ используется наряду с основным изъяснительным союзом ЧТО, но имеет дополнительные **смысловые оттенки ирреальности**, которые придаёт ему частица БЫ.

Вопрос:

Как определить вид придаточного в заданном предложении?

Это изъяснительный или целевой союз, как их различить по смыслу?

Что означает частица БЫ (в составе союза) в данном предложении?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По-моему, Вы уже в вопросе сами на него ответили.

*У меня нет времени (для чего?), чтобы играть.* - СПП с придаточным изъяснительным.

Союз или союзное слово - важная деталь, конечно, но главное в классификации всё-таки **правильно поставить вопрос** к придаточному. У нас вопрос изъяснительного придаточного. Есть и оттенки, во-первых - оттенок определительного (нет времени какого? - чтобы играть), во-вторых, цели (нет времени для какой цели?). Придаточное присловное -  распространяет контактное слово и присоединяется изъяснительным союзом чтобы. Союз **чтобы** указывает на ирреальную модальность объекта - **желательность, возможность или необходимость.**

Придаточные с союзом чтобы присоединяются не ко всем словам, нуждающимся в изъяснении, а только к таким, которые выражают сомнение, опасение, различные виды побуждений, модальные состояния. Например: сомневаюсь, чтобы... боюсь, чтобы не... беспокоюсь, чтобы не... приказал, чтобы...; просил, чтобы... просьба, чтобы... хочу, чтобы... нужно, чтобы... и др.

Частица БЫ всегда вносит оттенки сомнения, неуверенности или побуждения.

В данном для разбора предложении мы видим   отрицание возможности играть, побуждение не тратить время.